# I am using '->' but output is still asking me if I meant to use '->'

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer

I am trying to create the functionality of a Single-Linked List in C, but I am having an issue accessing the next node of my Head node.

```
typedef struct node {
  struct node *next;
} Node;

int foo(Node **head){
  *head = *head->next;
}
```

When I run this code, I expect it to change the address of my head node pointer to the next node over, but instead I receive the following error:

```
‘*head’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
     *head = *head->next;
```

Comment: Kahl,  If `*head->next` like `(*head)->next` or `*(head->next)`?

Comment: When I make head `Node *head = NULL;`, and the function call would look like `foo(&head)`.

Comment: According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence your `*head->next` is equivalent to `*(head->next)` . I doubt it is what you mean. More like `(*head)->next` don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line inside foo should be

```
     *head = (*head)->next
```

because '->' has higher precedence than *

You can learn more about operator precedence here (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)